# Combine react-sketchapp with regular sketch editing?

Tags: sketch-3, react-sketchapp

I've been playing a little with react-sketchapp, trying to understand its capabilities. I love the idea that basic components can be captured in code and dropped into Sketch for further editing...but as I look through the docs and examples, I'm not seeing how to accomplish the "further editing" part.

What I'd like, ideally, is to have react-sketchapp generate a bunch of symbols or layers, and then be able, in Sketch itself, to supply my own layers or symbol overrides. That way, I can use React for the reusable, stable components in the system, and Sketch to lay out mockups and do any custom work around those components.

As far as I can tell that isn't doable. When npm re-renders the React code, it blows away everything at the Page level and replaces (rather than modifies) all the symbols, meaning any overrides and custom layers/artboards are lost.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm looking for with react-sketchapp? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

[Check out this **Sketch Libraries & react-sketchap**p post](https://github.com/airbnb/react-sketchapp/issues/172) for progress.

> Wouldn't it be amazing that a react-sketchapp plugin would actually create a Sketch Library? You would run the plugin and boom , all your components are available as symbols to use in your design. Re-running it would just update the Library.